# Boot Ubuntu 13 from USB flash drive without software

Tags: boot, usb, flash

Can I boot Ubuntu 13 64-bit with the ISO installed on a USB flash drive (16GB)?  If so, how?  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, yes.

Try this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

scott

Answer (score 0):

While there are several options here, the one that has always worked (and worked well) for me is [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). You don't say what OS you're currently on, but this is cross platform.

Download your ISO, and use the Unetbootin GUI to do the rest. Very straightforward.